# NUnit Test for ActionResult which checks user roles

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I am currently new to ASPNET MVC framework and I wanted to do some unit testing using NUnit, and I am having difficulties.

My issue is that I have a controller and most of the `ActionResults` methods have got checks inside them checking whether the current login user belongs to certain roles, now my issue is how do I log in using `NUnit` so those `ActionResults` tests can be carries, otherwise they are returning `nullexception`.

The following is some of the code for the `Index()` Method to give you a overview of the situation. Could you also possibly point out what kind of things I can test in this?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      IEnumerable<Colour> colours = null;

      if (isUserAdmin())
      {
          colours = db.Colours;
      }
      else
      {
          string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
          IEnumerable<string> userRoleIds = db.Users.Find(userId).Roles.Select(x => x.Id);
          colours = db.ColourRoles.Where(x => userRoleIds.Contains(x.RoleId)).Select(y => y.Colour).Distinct();
      }

      ViewData["Colours"] = colours;            
      return View();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using a mocking framework such as moq?  Before you invoke the `Index` method in your test, you can mock httpcontext and controllercontext with a mock user/identity.  However, that may or may not fully solve your situation depending whether you are injecting `db` or need to do something to make that call work.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I am not using any mocking framework at all. I think this maybe a right mess. Is there anything else you could suggest me?

Comment: Refactor the code out of the controller to an interface and have a different implementation used when in Test.

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumption about your controller and using an idea from this walkthrough [Walkthrough: Using TDD with ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511%28VS.98%29.aspx), I think you can try this

```
[TestClass]
public class ControllerUnitTest {

    [TestMethod]
    public void ControllerIndexTest() {
        // Arrange
        var username = "[Test_Username_Here]";
        string[] roles = new[] { "FakeRoleId1", "FakeRoleId2" };
        var controller = new CollorsController(new FakeDbContext());
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
            Controller = controller,
            RequestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(username, roles), new RouteData())
        };

        // Act
        var actionResult = controller.Index();
        var viewResult = actionResult as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
        Assert.IsTrue(viewResult.ViewData.ContainsKey("Colours"));
    }

    private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
        private readonly IPrincipal user;

        public MockHttpContext(string username, string[] roles = null) {
           var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, string.Empty);
           var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles ?? new string[] { });
           user = principal;
        }

        public override IPrincipal User {
            get {
                return user;
            }
            set {
                base.User = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock HttpContext with [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page):

```
var username = "[Test_Username_Here]";
string[] roles = new[] { "FakeRoleId1", "FakeRoleId2" };
var fake = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<HttpContextBase>();
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(username, roles ?? new string[] { }));
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fake.User).WillReturn(user);
```